# Firebase Database Unity differentiating between old and new data

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat engine using firebase in unity. I want to differentiate between the existing data and all the new data that gets added into the database. There is method `once` in web sdk of firebase which helps in differentiating between old and new data, is anyone aware if we have something similar on unity

Comment: The method to read data once is called `GetValueAsync()` on Unity. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once.

Comment: but this does not helps in differentiating new and old data or can we ?

Comment: That's correct. There is nothing built-in to the Unity, Android, iOS or Web SDK to differentiate between new and old data. If you need such functionality, you'll have to build it into the app code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this, one way that is a workaround is to add a timestamp value in all the entries maintained in the database and each time one subscribes for the new data we make use of the `OrderByValue|OrderByKey` and `StartAt` to do the same.

In the beginning value for `StartAt` will be 0 but post that whenever a child gets added we can update the `StartAt` value to that so that the next time client subscribes for the childAdded, it will only receive data post the last child.